# XMLWriter add new element to document start

Tags: php, xmlwriter

Flow is like that:

```
    $xml = new XMLWriter();
    $xml->openURI('file.xml');
    $xml->setIndent(4);
    $xml->startDocument('1.0');

    $xml->startElement('second');
    $xml->endElement();
```

Now I want add element at start (before second)

```
    $xml->startElement('first');
    $xml->endElement();
```

How I can mode element first before second ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`XMLWriter` not have option to manipulate with nodes (apend after, apend before), so no build in solution for that issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can add your element in an array and sort him like you want. By key for example.

After, you can use foreach (or other) for add your elements

```
$elements[1] = 'second';
# do somethings
$elements[0] = 'first';

    foreach ($elements as $key => $element) {
        $xml->startElement($element);
    }
```

Comment: I don't understand your coment. It's if you putting text to the indexes ?

Comment: Yes, putting to the indexes

Comment: Why you need txt in indexes ? You can't use a multi dimentional array like that ? :
`$elements[0]['libelle'] = 'lib';
$elements[0]['value'] = 'your_content';
 foreach ($elements as $key => $element) {
  echo $element['libelle'];
  echo '<br/>';
  echo $element['value'];
 }
`
If you need more help, please explain better your problem